# Mock External method calls from class In Juints

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am trying to mock a call to instance of another class from my class. The issue I am seeing is that it looks like my mock object is not being replaced with the real object when I run my test. I made a simple example here to explain the case. Here I want to print `tada` instead of `this is awsome` which the method `printAwsome()` does by default. I have put my code in link below for reference please let me know what am I doing wrong if anything.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1eab366c60efb75b9075f100a67c851b

ExcelSupporTest prints `this is awsome` instead of `tada` when I try to mock `optionPane.printAwsome()` can someone point me to what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I don't see anything mocked above. Could you share the code where you are trying to mock method/class please. I don't see any tests above as well.

Comment: I made a simpler version to remove overhead have a look and let me know if this helps

Comment: you have changes the question 360 with the code removed as well. Please improve the question for better understanding. This shall also help update the answer accordingly to the question

Comment: I do apologize for that but I did this to make it a lot simpler and straightforward .

Comment: Can people downvoting please specifiy why so that I can correct it or made appropriate edits

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please go through

Comment: please let me know if this is better and thank you for sharing the link with me. Also if you think this is more apt please upvote it

Answer (score 0):

To what I can infer form the question, if you are trying to mock a call to the method `showMessageDialog`, try mocking `DefaultOptionPane` as follows:

```
DefaultOptionPane defaultOptionPane = mock(DefaultOptionPane.class);
when(defaultOptionPane.showMessageDialog(anyObject(), anyObject(), anyString(), anyInt()))
                .then(//do what you want to do here <Answer>);
```

What this simply means as its readable as well is whenever you make a call to `showMessageDialog` with any set of params you want to return something that you state as an `Answer` in `then`.

Comment: I tried that but it still goes inside showMessageDialog cant seem to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

So long story short unless you pass it in as a  parameter to method you cannot mock the method call.

It becomes an issue with scoping so replace this

```
   public void testMethod() {
        DefaultOptionPane optionPane = new DefaultOptionPane();
        System.out.println("Entering method");
        optionPane.printAwsome();
        System.out.println("Exiting Method");
      }
```

with this

```
 public void testMethod(DefaultOptionPane optionPane) {

        System.out.println("Entering method");
        System.out.println(optionPane.printAwsome());
        System.out.println("Exiting Method");
    }
```

and then you can mock the `optionPane`

Comment: No, I don't think you are mocking anything still in this piece of code.

Comment: I replaced the code with gist link which has ExcelSupportTest.java in which I am mocking optionPane.printAwsome() .

Comment: I changed the code to something simpler to not overwhelm people with unnecessary details